# Kotlin set lazy field through Java reflection

Tags: java, kotlin, reflection

I'm trying to play around with Java reflection in Kotlin, and I have the following field in my Kotlin class:

```
val tree: Tree by lazy { 
    getTree(hashGroup, service) 
}
```

I'd like to set this field through Java reflection, and so far I got to this point:

```
val tField = transaction::class.java.getDeclaredField("tree\$delegate")
tField.isAccessible = true
tField.set(transaction, newTree)
```

Obviously this is not going to work, because the `tree` field has a delegate (`tree$delegate`) and it wants me to set it to a `Lazy` class type and not `Tree` type.

I know the easiest would be to actually add a setter for this field in the main class but I can't really modify the API and I need this for a resilience test case. Is this even possible to do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just create a `Lazy<T>` instance like you normally would!

If you want to set it to the constant value `newTree`:

```
tField.set(transaction, lazyOf(newTree))
```

You can also set a new block of code for it to be evaluated lazily:

```
tField.set(transaction, lazy {
    Tree().apply {
        // do something lazily to this tree...
    }
})
```

Comment: Getting this error:  `Can not set static final kotlin.Lazy field fieldName$delegate to kotlin.InitializedLazyImpl `when using `lazyOf`, and getting : `Can not set static final fieldName$delegate to kotlin.SynchronizedLazyImpl` when using `lazy{}`, any solution?

Comment: @SurajVaishnav It seems like whatever you have became a *static* field on the JVM side? Those are known to be tricky to set with reflection. See [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3301635/5133585). Alternatively, find a way to make a non-static.